# slicehost google apps mx settings

Tags: email, g-suite, slicehost, mx-record

I am banging my head against the wall on this one. I followed the MX setup tutorials for Google Mail and it didn't work. Currently, after deleting those records and adding the ones google suggested I have

```
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  30 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  30 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domain.com.     86400   IN  MX  30 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
```

according to the output of my dig command for my particular "domain".

I can send email from google apps mail but I can not recieve any email. It gives me the following error:

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 #5.1.0 Address rejected name@domain.com

Now I already tried following the slicehost MX article instructions straight as well and they did not work out for me. The domain has already been verified by google and it says the email is activated from their end. Any help would be appreciated : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what the TTL settings were on the previous MX records?  The resolver used by the sending server may still have the old information cached.  When making DNS changes, it is generally recommended to lower the TTL settings as low as possible (120 seconds perhaps) at least [the current value] time in advance.  This way, when you make changes, other servers will not cache the old information very long and the previous data will have expired from cache when you make the change.  Then, once the change has been made and verified, you can increase the TTL value once more.  In this question, you're using 86400 (24 hours) as the TTL, so old data can take up to that long to expire from cache before the new information will be seen by some servers.

The bounce error itself just means that whatever MX record the sender is seeing doesn't have the mailbox that you're trying to send to.  If that mailbox exists at Google, the sending server likely has the old MX record cached and you'll have to wait until that old DNS data expires before it will go fetch your updated records and send to the right receiving server.

Comment: hey justin, they were about one week I believe on the original settings because I was following google's instructions. Thanks for the response and it seems that this may just be the issue. I appreciate it.